# How to restart app programatically when screen is Off in Nougat

Tags: android

This code works till marshmallow, when I am restarting my application. This code works Even in Nougat when screen is on. This piece of code is not able to restart application in Nougat only when screen is Off

Any help would be appreciated :

```
        Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainClass.class);
        int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
        PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), mPendingIntentId,    mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, mPendingIntent);
        finish();
        System.gc();
        System.exit(0);
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem but why are you calling `System.gc();` here? It is seldom a good idea to do this in general but just before exit it is pointless.

Comment: @harry any suggestions. I will remove System.gc() any way.